# How can I vectorize this for loop (matlab)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I appreciate advice on how I might vectorize the following for loop (matlab):

```
    summ=0;
    for i=1:lasti
         summ=summ+abs(newTS(m+i*k)-newTS(m+(i-1)*k));
    end
```

By vectorize I mean use matrix operations instead of the for loop.  I have heard that vectorization is generally more efficient and quicker than for loops.

EDIT: Actually what I would really like to vectorize is below.  I include it in case some brave soul wants to give it a shot...

```
   for j=1:length(kvec)
       k=kvec(j);
       for m=1:k
           lasti=floor((N-m)/k);
           Nfact=(N-1)/(lasti*k);
           summ=0;
           for i=1:lasti
                summ=summ+abs(newTS(m+i*k)-newTS(m+(i-1)*k));
           end
           L(m,j)=(summ*Nfact)/k;
           %Avg over m
           AvgL(j)=mean(L(:,j));
        end
    end
```

Comment: You should specify of which size the variables ´m´ and ´k´ are and whether `newTS()´ also works on vectors. Otherwise this question cannot be answered that well.

Comment: Also specify if `newTS` is a function or just a matrix that you are extracting elements out of. If `newTS` is a function, it'll have to be vectorized before this loop can be fully optimized.

Comment: @H.Muster I think the size of m and k should be clear after the edit I just made.

Comment: @user57368 newTS is a column vector, not a function.

Comment: Also, I think the code line `AvgL(j)=mean(L(:,j));` should be outside the `m` loop. Please edit it. My edit was rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to sum all the distance between `newTS(m+i*k)` and `newTS(m+(i-1)*k)`, so you can do something like this

```
summ = sum(abs(diff(newTS(m:k:m+lasti*k))))
```

I agree with you that in my experience with Matlab, matrix operation is usually MUCH faster than `for` loops. I try to avoid them as much as I can.

EDIT: I think replace the inner `i` loop should be good enough for you. Maybe you can replace the `m` loop by reshape `newTS` into a matrix, but since `lasti` is different for each `m`, it could be tricky in your case.

Comment: Thanks.  There is some issue with the increment :k: but I think I can work it out based on this answer.

Comment: @ben Make sure `k` is an integer.

Comment: Yes k is an integer.  The problem is that the difference is between the ith element and the i-1th element, so I have to figure some way to offset one of the columns by one element.